# Global setting of Resources menu in Joomla like Main menu

Tags: joomla1.5

In **Joomla** there are **Main Menu** and **Resources** menu, the **Main Menu** is available on all pages but the **Resources** menu does not, how could we apply same setting to **Resources**  menu so that we can access **Resources** menu as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty simple, do the following

1. Go to Admin BackEnd -> Tools -> Module Manager
2. In modules find your Resources menu, click on it
3. Find section Menu Assignment and select "ALL"
4. Save Changes

You can also [look at documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Screen.modules.edit.15), might learn some useful tricks.

Test the front end to make sure everything works the way you want it.